# Mybatis RowBounds with collection inside resultMap not returning expected result

Tags: java, pagination, mybatis

**Mapper.xml**

```
<resultMap id="resultMap" type="dBWrapper">
    <result property="id" column="id" />
    <result property="code" column="code" />
    <result property="description" column="description" />
    <collection property="orderIds" ofType="java.lang.Long" >
        <result column="orderId" />
    </collection>
</resultMap>

<select id="selectAllProducts" resultMap="resultMap" parameterType="dBWrapper">
    SELECT product.id, product.code, product.description, provider.providerName, order.orderId
    FROM Product product
    LEFT JOIN Order order on product.id = order.productId
    WHERE 1=1
    <if orderSearchId != ''> 
        and order.orderId = #{orderSearchId}
    </if>
</select>
```

Java code written to retrieve a paged list:

```
productList = productMapper.selectAllProducts(searchObj, new RowBounds((searchObj.getPage() - 1) * searchObj.getTotal(), searchObj.getTotal()));
```

such that for page 1 with 3 records, it is called with RowBounds(0, 3). For page 2, it is called with RowBounds(3, 3), for page 3 RowBounds(6, 3).

The SQL query for the above function in mybatis logs returns the following

```
id      code      description      orderId
-------------------------------------------
1       101       Samolina         200
1       101       Samolina         201
2       102       Trampoline       300
2       102       Trampoline       301
2       102       Trampoline       302
2       102       Trampoline       303
3       103       Pajar            401
3       103       Pajar            402
4       104       Tramtor          500
4       104       Tramtor          501
4       104       Tramtor          502
5       105       Wadnor           600
5       105       Wadnor           601
5       105       Wadnor           602
5       105       Wadnor           603
6       106       Bramget          701
6       106       Bramget          702
```

However, when **mybatis** applies paging and collection, the following records are seen on the first page (which is fine).

```
id      code      description      orderIds
-------------------------------------------
1       101       Samolina         (200,201)
2       102       Trampoline       (300,301,302,303)
3       103       Pajar            (401,402)
```

Hence for the second page, the records should start from id = 4. However, this is what returned for the second page by mybatis.

```
id      code      description      orderIds
-------------------------------------------
2       102       Trampoline       (301,302,303)
3       103       Pajar            (401,402)
4       104       Tramtor          (500,501,502)
```

Now if you look at what database returned for the actual query, the 4th record is below. And this is where the 2nd page actually started. Notice the missing orderId of 300 in the first record of page 2. Its because the orderId = 300 was the 3rd record in the actual query, hence its not included.

```
id      code      description      orderId
-------------------------------------------
2       102       Trampoline       301
```

Is there something I am missing about mybatis pagination or collections?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue. Answer by The Impaler has some valid points but doesn't solve the issue. As I see it, mybatis has no (simple) way of knowing how to setup limits for the query as the number of rows corresponding to a single item in the result is variable.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues in your code:

- If you are using pagination, you need to add `ORDER BY` to your SQL. When not present SQL returns the rows in **any** order, and the order may/will change over time. I think this is a critical mistake in your code.
- Also, it's highly advisable to to specify the < id > tag on some properties of the enclosing entity. Otherwise it can become really slow.
- Also, use the < where > clause instead of `WHERE 1=1`. MyBatis will remove the first `and` automatically at runtime if needed.

Here's a modified version of your mapper:

```
<resultMap id="resultMap" type="dBWrapper">
    <id property="id" column="id" /> <!-- I used ID here -->
    <result property="code" column="code" />
    <result property="description" column="description" />
    <collection property="orderIds" ofType="java.lang.Long" >
        <result column="orderId" />
    </collection>
</resultMap>

<select id="selectAllProducts" resultMap="resultMap" parameterType="dBWrapper">
    SELECT product.id, product.code, product.description, 
      provider.providerName, order.orderId
    FROM Product product
    LEFT JOIN Order order on product.id = order.productId
    <where>
      <if test="orderSearchId != null"> 
        and order.orderId = #{orderSearchId}
      </if>
    </where>
    ORDER BY product.id, order.id
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Impaler has valid points. But it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

The problem can be solved by rewriting the sql [as discussed by Kazuki Shimizu](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Way-to-do-paging-use-by-RowBounds-on-a-entity-that-has-nested-result-map-td4028431.html).
Basically you have to limit some inner/intermediate table that will in the end represent actual entities returned from MyBatis mapper.

Or if you don't have many entries in the database, you can implement paging in code while retrieving all(!) items.

```
public List<Item> getItems(Paging paging) {
    List<Item> items = itemMapper.selectItems();
    if (paging != null) {
        items = items.stream()
                .skip((long) paging.pageIndex * paging.pageSize)
                .limit(paging.pageSize)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: For paging in code I would use `sublist()`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-
Also note that you don't really need to retrieve all items, just `limit + 1` (the last one will be "wrong" but it will be discarded by paging in code), offset must be zero.